# How to get the session Id in site page using Ajax tool kit

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, ajax-toolkit

I have a visualforce page in which I have used Ajax tool kit for search functionality. Its working fine in Vf page. But when I rendered the page Using Sites Iam unable to get sessionId.

How can I get sessionId in Sites page without using any username and password.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get session Id in visualforce if your visualforce page is hosted on `force.com` site.
If you have controller then by creating getter you can initialize the session Id and refer it again in visualforce page.

In controller :

```
public string sessionId {get;private set;}
```

Initialize this in constructor :

```
sessionId  = UserInfo.getSessionId();
```

and refer in visualforce page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var __sfdcSessionId = '{!sessionId}';
</script>
```

hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

The main use of using sites is to make pages publicly accessible.

A valid user session is not established unless user log's in to salesforce using any of the login mechanisms(SSO, Communities, salesforce login..,)